# Docker-compose not reading the environment variables to write logs to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, docker-compose, serilog

I am setting up docker-compose.yml file to read the environment variables for the docker image. I have serilog.sinks.elasticsearch nuget package referenced in my host project.

If I run the project in Visual Studio with appsettings.json, it reads the settings and sends to logs to Elasticsearch but not through docker-compose.

docker-compose.yml environment specification for docker image:

```
environment:
      - serilog:MinimumLevel=Verbose
      - serilog:using=Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch
      - serilog:WriteTo:Elasticsearch.nodeUris=http://localhost:9200
```

Local appsettings.json works.

```
"Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "Elasticsearch",
                "Args": {
                    "nodeUris": "http://localhost:9200"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

MinimumLevel set in docker-compose gets respected.

How to set the docker-compose.yml to read the sink and send the logs to elasticsearch database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use double underscore separator, for example - `Serilog__MinimumLevel=Verbose`. Double underscore is a default separator for `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables` package(If you're not override it in your `ConfigurationBuilder` composition code). [MSDN Environment Variables Configuration Provider reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider)

Array Environment variable setting is requiring index specification.

Check this:

```
Serilog__Using__0=Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch
Serilog__WriteTo__0__Name=Elasticsearch
Serilog__WriteTo__0__Args__nodeUris=http://localhost:9200
```

Comment: MinimumLevel gets read from docker-compose.yml. using and WriteTo are not getting read. I tried double underscore and its not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kabali, check my updated comment. The main idea - try to specify all values with correct key/value env pairs. Also you should check your `configurationBuilder` hierarchy. The last specified configuration extension have the biggest priority.

Comment: But if you have the whole section in base `appsettings.json`, then you should override all values in a section to match accepted configuration.

Comment: This works, thanks. I still have it as : instead of __ and it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kabali, Please, check the answer as resolved if it suits to your question. Thanks

Comment: Sure I will do it.

Answer (score 2):

following answers worked. shout out to @SKorolchuk.

```
- serilog:MinimumLevel=Verbose
- Serilog:WriteTo:0:Name=Elasticsearch
- serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:nodeUris=http://localhost:9200
```

or

```
Serilog__Using__0=Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch
Serilog__WriteTo__0__Name=Elasticsearch
Serilog__WriteTo__0__Args__nodeUris=http://localhost:9200
```